# Ext.Net (ext.axd is not loading) not working with Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, azure, ext.net, webresource.axd

I am trying to build a Windows Azure site with Ext.Net. This project can be downloaded [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6FFvzJ98JwTVXN2RU41cm44M1U/edit). 
I am getting below errors whenever I try to look the sample (Ext.NET.Default.aspx) page on browser (on local)

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
  (Not Found) => localhost/extnet/extnet-all-js/ext.axd?v=40838
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) =>   localhost/extjs/ext-all-js/ext.axd?v=40838
- Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined Ext.NET.Default.aspx:14

RegisterRoute is:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaxd}", new { allaxd = @".*\.axd(/.*)?" });

        //routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{handler}.ashx");
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("extnet/{*pathInfo}");
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("extjs/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("icons/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Resources/{*pathInfo}");
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("{handler}.axd");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
    }
```